# Is the following data in ASCII format? If not how would I use python3 to convert it into ASCII characters

Tags: python-3.x

So I have the following data and I want to use matplotlib to plot it, but I need to make sure my data is in ASCII format first. If it is great, but if not how would I convert it into ASCII format using python 3?

2019-05-19 13:15:15 CDT 3.4000000000e+01

Comment: Looks like it is, unless there's some weird Unicode space or something. Please check [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) to see if all the characters of your string are present there

Comment: The only thing is the last value  3.4000000000e+01, its supposed to be equal to 34 C the form is just weird. Converting it just weird because of how it is written in the data file

Comment: Well, all the characters that form `3.4000000000e+01` are ASCII, so it should be fine. `3.4000000000e+01` is the same as `34.0000e+00` and `340.0000e-01` - it's just notation